# Can a subject and its complement be of different numbers?

Tags: grammatical-number, subjects, linking-verbs, subject-complement

Can a subject and a subject complement be of different numbers, i.e. one of them is plural and the other is singular?
To check this, I came up with some examples
(where, as I understand, "are", "is", "represent" and "represents" are linking verbs):

**(1a)** The letters "u" and "n" **are** the prefix of "uncommon".
**(1b)** The letters "u" and "n" **is** the prefix of "uncommon".

**(1c)** The prefix of "uncommon" **is** the letters "u" and "n".
**(1d)** The prefix of "uncommon" **are** the letters "u" and "n".

**(2a)** The letters "u" and "n" **represent** the prefix of "uncommon".
**(2b)** The letters "u" and "n" **represents** the prefix of "uncommon".

**(2c)** The prefix of "uncommon" **represents** the letters "u" and "n".
**(2d)** The prefix of "uncommon" **represent** the letters "u" and "n".

Could you tell me please which of them are correct and which are not?

Comment: By "represent(s)", is it possible you mean "form(s)"? The letters "u" and "n" *are* the prefix, not a representation of it. "Form" is also a linking verb, and has the meaning that the prefix is made up of "u" and "n". I don't think it changes the substance of your question to use "form" instead.

Comment: Also, sentences 2c and 2d don't make any sense. You should use the passive voice, whether you use "represent(s)" or "form(s).

Comment: @gotube Can I infer from your comments that: FIRST ITEM) the number of a linking verb depends on a subject (that goes first in sentences) but not on a subject complement (that goes after a linking verb); Hence: SECOND ITEM) (1a)&(1c) are correct, (1b)&(1d) are incorrect; THIRD ITEM) also, if we replace "_represent(s)_" with "_form(s)_" (that is a linking verb here too), then, by the same logic, (2a) is correct and (2b) is incorrect. Are the items correct? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the number of any subject... but (1) is correct. (2) is not correct because in that context, *the letters "u" and "n"* could be reasonably understood as a single object: "(the combination of) the letters "u" and "n", so they're both grammatical. (3) So by the same logic, 2a and 2b are both correct.